# how to check if audio file link is not loaded in html5 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what is the fastest way to check if audio link is invalid (and alert)?

```
<audio controls src="http://example.com/file/notfound.mp3">
 browser not supported
</audio>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/juyg1zf8/2/)

Comment: `audioElement.onerror` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching little bit, this is what I found:

```
$("#postaudiotag").on("click", function () {
    try {
        $('audio')[0].play();
    } catch (e) {
            alert('error playing file')
    }
});

$("#audiomp3").on("error", function (e) {
    alert('mp3 file is not found');
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/juyg1zf8/10/)

Comment: Your try-catch is completely useless. `play` never throws.  In newest browsers you could do `play().catch(...)` since it now returns a Promise, but it's a different code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
myAudio.onerror = function(error) {

  console.error(error);
}
```

With HTML:

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls src="http://example.com/file/notfound.mp3">
  browser not supported
</audio>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juyg1zf8/4/).

Comment: i'm not asking if browser is unsupported. I'm asking if `src link` is invalid

Comment: Updated the answer.